# Tree Dynamically Form Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, dynamic, entity, symfony6

I have 5 tables:
1.event - id, name, location
2.location - id, country_id, county_id, city_id
3.country - id, name
4.county - id, name, country_id,
5. city - id, name, county_id

I can get to work for populate city select box

I have 2 form types
EventLocationType and LocationType

Thank you in advance!

I have try to make city box to work but i don;t know how to do it!
Thanks!

```php
class EventLocationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('location', LocationType::class, [
            'label' => false,

        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => EventLocation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder->add('country', CountryTypeSelect::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'not null',
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('county', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'not null',
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'attr'  => [ 'class' => 'form-control'],          
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'not null',
                ]),
            ],
        ]);

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
            $counties_array = [];
            if($country != null) {
                $g = new GeoNamesClient('djmichael');
                [$countryGeoNames] = $g->countryInfo([
                        'country' => $country->getName(),
                ]);
                $country_name = $countryGeoNames->geonameId;
                $counties_json = $g->children(['geonameId' => $country_name]);

                foreach($counties_json as $counties_j) {
                    //dd($counties_j->toponymName);
                    $counties_array[$counties_j->toponymName] = $counties_j->geonameId;
                }
                //dd($counties);
            } 
            //var_dump($counties);
            $counties = null === $counties_array ? [] : $counties_array;
            
            $form->add('county', ChoiceType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
                'required'  => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'choices' => $counties,
                //'mapped'    => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'not null',
                    ]),
                ],
            ]);
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();
                //
                $country = null;
                if($data != null) {
                    $country = $data->getCountry();
                    //dd($data);
                }
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $country);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier)  {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
                if($country->getName() != null) {
                    $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
                } else {
                    $formModifier2($event->getForm(), $county);
                }
                //dd($country);
                
            }
                
        );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Location::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
var $country = $('#event_location_location_country_name');
    var $token = $('#event_location__token');
    var $county = $('#event_location_location_county');
    // When country gets selected ...
    $country.change(function () {
        // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        // Simulate form data, but only include the selected country value.
        var data = {};
        data[$country.attr('name')] = $country.val();
        data[$token.attr('name')] = $token.val();
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: data,
            complete: function (html) {
                //console.log(html.responseText);
                // Replace current state field ...
                $('#event_location_location_county').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html.responseText).find('#event_location_location_county')
                );
            },
        });
    });

    $county.change(function () {
        // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        // Simulate form data, but only include the selected country value.
        var data = {};
        data[$country.attr('name')] = $county.val();
        data[$token.attr('name')] = $token.val();
        console.log(data);
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: data,
            complete: function (html) {
                //console.log(html.responseText);
                // Replace current state field ...
                $('#event_location_city').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html.responseText).find('#event_location_city')
                );
            },
        });
    });
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EventLocationRepository::class)]
class EventLocation
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 128, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'eventLocations', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Location $location = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocation(): ?Location
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    public function setLocation(?Location $location): self
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LocationRepository::class)]
class Location
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'locations', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?Country $country = null;
    
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'locations', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?County $county = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'locations')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?City $city = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'location', targetEntity: EventLocation::class)]
    private Collection $eventLocations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventLocations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?Country
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(?Country $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCounty(): ?County
    {
        return $this->county;
    }

    public function setCounty(?County $county): self
    {
        $this->county = $county;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?City
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?City $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, EventLocation>
     */
    public function getEventLocations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->eventLocations;
    }

    public function addEventLocation(EventLocation $eventLocation): self
    {
        if (!$this->eventLocations->contains($eventLocation)) {
            $this->eventLocations->add($eventLocation);
            $eventLocation->setLocation($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEventLocation(EventLocation $eventLocation): self
    {
        if ($this->eventLocations->removeElement($eventLocation)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($eventLocation->getLocation() === $this) {
                $eventLocation->setLocation(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CountryRepository::class)]
class Country
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 128, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'country', targetEntity: County::class)]
    private Collection $counties;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'country', targetEntity: Location::class)]
    private Collection $locations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->counties = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->locations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, County>
     */
    public function getCounties(): Collection
    {
        return $this->counties;
    }

    public function addCounty(County $county): self
    {
        if (!$this->counties->contains($county)) {
            $this->counties->add($county);
            $county->setCountry($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCounty(County $county): self
    {
        if ($this->counties->removeElement($county)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($county->getCountry() === $this) {
                $county->setCountry(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Location>
     */
    public function getLocations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->locations;
    }

    public function addLocation(Location $location): self
    {
        if (!$this->locations->contains($location)) {
            $this->locations->add($location);
            $location->setCountry($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLocation(Location $location): self
    {
        if ($this->locations->removeElement($location)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($location->getCountry() === $this) {
                $location->setCountry(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CountyRepository::class)]
class County
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 128, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'counties')]
    private ?Country $country = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'county', targetEntity: City::class)]
    private Collection $cities;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'county', targetEntity: Location::class)]
    private Collection $locations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cities = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->locations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?Country
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(?Country $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, City>
     */
    public function getCities(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cities;
    }

    public function addCity(City $city): self
    {
        if (!$this->cities->contains($city)) {
            $this->cities->add($city);
            $city->setCounty($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCity(City $city): self
    {
        if ($this->cities->removeElement($city)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($city->getCounty() === $this) {
                $city->setCounty(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Location>
     */
    public function getLocations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->locations;
    }

    public function addLocation(Location $location): self
    {
        if (!$this->locations->contains($location)) {
            $this->locations->add($location);
            $location->setCounty($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLocation(Location $location): self
    {
        if ($this->locations->removeElement($location)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($location->getCounty() === $this) {
                $location->setCounty(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CityRepository::class)]
class City
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 128, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'cities')]
    private ?County $county = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'city', targetEntity: Location::class)]
    private Collection $locations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->locations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCounty(): ?County
    {
        return $this->county;
    }

    public function setCounty(?County $county): self
    {
        $this->county = $county;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Location>
     */
    public function getLocations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->locations;
    }

    public function addLocation(Location $location): self
    {
        if (!$this->locations->contains($location)) {
            $this->locations->add($location);
            $location->setCity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLocation(Location $location): self
    {
        if ($this->locations->removeElement($location)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($location->getCity() === $this) {
                $location->setCity(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, the dumb and still correct answer is, that at the point where you add the sub forms, those subforms need to get their own event listener that would add the sub sub forms, i.e. in $formmodifier, at the end, you have to add another formmodifier to add cities. I mean, you already found the first step of the solution, and the second step is essentially the same. event listeners all the way down the tree.

Comment: I am getting a javascript message in ajax - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 () . After showing me the county fields is stoping there because of 422 error.

Comment: cool, I've never seen 422. however, glancing over your code, you got in your county.change: `data[$country.attr('name')] = $county.val();`, this seems like there is an extra `r`. Assuming your corresponding controller code is correct, this could be the source of your sorrows? ^^

Comment: Thanks so much, meanwhile, the problem of 422 it was because of return render in controller. The correct way to avoid 422 is return render without renderForm. Ex: $this->render('event_location/new.html.twig', [ 'event_location' => $eventLocation, 'form' => $form->createView(), ]);

Answer (score 0):

First part is working, ok, but in the second part I see in controller is not capturing anything - https://prnt.sc/I9Gl0Z6ooCo_

In `FormType` county  post submit is not working.

```
class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
  private $transformer;

  public function __construct(IssueToStringTransformer $transformer)
  {
    $this->transformer = $transformer;
  }
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $builder->add('country', CountryType::class, [
      'label' => false,
      'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
          'message' => 'not null',
        ]),
      ],
      'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control'
      ],
      //'empty_data' => ''
      //'mapped' => false,
    ])
    ->add('county', ChoiceType::class, [
      'label' => false,
      'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
      'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
          'message' => 'not null',
        ]),
      ],
    ])
    ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
      'label' => false,
      'attr'  => [ 'class' => 'form-control'],          
      'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
      'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
          'message' => 'not null',
        ]),
      ],
    ]);

    $builder->get('country')
      ->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
      $counties_array = [];
      // var_dump($country);
      if ($country != null) {
        $g = new GeoNamesClient('djmichael');
        [$countryGeoNames] = $g->countryInfo([
          'country' => $country->getName(),
        ]);
        $country_name = $countryGeoNames->geonameId;
        $counties_json = $g->children(['geonameId' => $country_name]);

        foreach($counties_json as $counties_j) {
          //dd($counties_j->toponymName);
          $counties_array[$counties_j->toponymName] = $counties_j->geonameId;
        }      
      } 
            
      $counties = null === $counties_array ? [] : $counties_array;
      //var_dump($counties);
      $form->add('county', ChoiceType::class, [
        'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
        //'required'  => false,
        'attr' => [
          'class' => 'form-control'
        ],
        'choices' => $counties,
        'constraints' => [
          new NotBlank([
            'message' => 'not null',
          ]),
        ],
      ]);
    };

    $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
        $data = $event->getData();
                
        $country = null;
        if ($data != null) {
          $country = $data->getCountry();
          //dd($data);
        } 
        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
      }
    );

    $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier)  {
        // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
        // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
        $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
        if ($country != null) {
          //dd($country);
          $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
        } else {
          //dd($country);
        }              
      }          
    );

    $builder->get('county')->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier)  {
        // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
        // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
        $county = $event->getForm()->getData();
        dd($county);
        if ($county != null) {
          //dd($country);
          $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $county);
        } else {
          //dd($country);
        }              
      }          
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spent some good time, i finally found the solution for
Countries->Counties->Cities
With the help from another stackoverflow post, i create a event Subscriber.
I also use geoname.org and change from post_submit to pre_submit

So the final looks like this:

```
    class DynamicFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface 
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA    => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT      => 'preSubmitData',
        ];
    }

     /**
     * Handling form fields before form renders.
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        //dd($data);
        $country = null;
        if($data != null) {
            //$country = $data->getCountry();
            dd($data);
        }
        $this->addCountyData($form, $country); 
    }

     /**
     * Handling form fields before form renders.
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSubmitData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $location['country'] = $event->getData();
                //dd($location);
        if(array_key_exists('country', $location['country'])) { 
            //dd($country);
            $countryObj = new Country();
            $countryObj->setName($location['country']['country']);
            //dd($country);
            $this->addCountyData($event->getForm(), $countryObj);
        }  else {
            $country = null;
            $countyGeoId = $location['country']['county'];
            //dd($countyGeoId);
            $this->addCityData($event->getForm(), $countyGeoId);
        }           
    }

    /**
     * Method to Add State Field. (first dynamic field.)
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param type $county
     */

    private function addCountyData(FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
        $countiesArray = [];
        if($country != null) {
            $geoNamesClient = new GeoNamesClient('djmichael');
            [$countryGeoNames] = $geoNamesClient->countryInfo([
                    'country' => $country->getName(),
            ]);
            $countryName = $countryGeoNames->geonameId;
            $countiesJson = $geoNamesClient->children(['geonameId' => $countryName]);
            foreach($countiesJson as $countyJson) {
                $countiesArray[$countyJson->toponymName] = $countyJson->geonameId;
            }
        } 
 
        $counties = null === $countiesArray ? [] : $countiesArray;        
        $form->add('county', ChoiceType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
            'mapped'  => false,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ],
            'choices' => $counties,
           // 'data'  => 'Tirana',
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'not null',
                ]),
            ],           
        ]);
    }

      /**
     * Method to Add State Field. (first dynamic field.)
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param type $city
     */

    private function addCityData(FormInterface $form, $county = null) {
        $citiesArray = [];
        if($county != null) {      
            $geoNamesClient = new GeoNamesClient('djmichael');
            $citiesJson = $geoNamesClient->children(['geonameId' => $county]);
            foreach($citiesJson as $cityJson) {
                $citiesArray[$cityJson->toponymName] = $cityJson->toponymName;
            }
        }

        $cities = null === $citiesArray ? [] : $citiesArray;

        $form->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
            'mapped'  => false,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ],
            'choices' => $cities,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'not null',
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
    }
} 

class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
private $transformer;

public function __construct(IssueToStringTransformer $transformer)
{
    $this->transformer = $transformer;
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{

    $builder->add('country', CountryType::class, [
        'label' => false,
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank([
                'message' => 'not null',
            ]),
        ],
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ],
        //'empty_data' => ''
        //'mapped' => false,
    ])
    ->add('county', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => County::class,
        'label' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank([
                'message' => 'not null',
            ]),
        ],
        'mapped'  => false,
    ])
    ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => false,
        'attr'  => [ 'class' => 'form-control'],          
        'placeholder' => 'Choose an option', 
        //'choices' => ['Tirana' => 'Tirana'],
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank([
                'message' => 'not null',
            ]),
        ],
        'mapped'  => false,
    ]);

    $builder->get('city')->resetViewTransformers();

    $builder->get('country')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);  

    $builder->addEventSubscriber(new DynamicFieldsSubscriber());  

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Location::class,
    ]);
}
}
```